# Constructing composite Galois field with arbitrary primitive polynomial?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

I am trying to construct a Galois field $GF(2^{10})$ from the field $GF(2^5)$ by making a composite field $GF((2^5)^2)$. The method I am using is to find a primitive polynomial of the field $GF(2^{10})$ $x^2+x+p_0$ with ground field $GF(2^5)$. However, I am not having success when the primitive polynomial $GF(2^{10})$ is $x^{10}+x^3+1$. None of the 32 possible values of $p_0$ work. Am I doing something wrong or is it just impossible to achieve what I want for a specific primitive polynomial?

What I am eventually trying to accomplish is to implement the composite Galois field multiplier described on pp. 8-10 of [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/324b/f468d6ff9b530ffaf515d02b4b6c162f83f0.pdf) paper for $GF(2^{10})$ but I cannot find the value of $p_0$.

Comment: That article mentions that $x^2+x+p_0$ is primitive for some $p_0\in\mathbb{F}_{32}$. It does not state that you can get all primitive polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$ in that way. Note that there are $60$ primitive polynomials of degree $10$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: If you want $\alpha^2+\alpha+p_0=0$ with $\alpha\not\in\mathrm{GF}(2^5)$, then the conjugate of $\alpha$ should be $\alpha^{32}$ as well as $\alpha+1$. In other words, $\alpha^{32}+\alpha+1=0$, but your degree-10 polynomial does not divide that.

Comment: In fact, $x^{32}+x+1 = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^{10} + x^9 + x^8 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(x^{10} + x^9 + x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1)(x^{10} + x^9 + x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x + 1)$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Thus, there are three degree-10 polynomials that work; the others won't.

Comment: @WimC I feared this was the case, thank you.

Comment: @ccorn Thank you for finding these polynomials. I also found an article [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3455/c2767418b7a1852eb6628e0dbb9c5631399e.pdf) explaining how to convert between $GF(2^k)$ with arbitrary primitive polynomial and $GF(2^{nm})$, now I just need to find out if implementing this conversion still leads to a less complex multiplier implementation than the standard implementation (I suspect not).

Comment: @ccorn and to the OP - late comment here, but $GF(2^{10}): x^{10}+x^3+1$ with primitive element $α(x)$ to be searched for, can be mapped using $GF(2^5): x^5 + x^2 + 1$, to $GF((2^5)^2): x^2 + x + 3$, with primitive element $β(x) = x$. This requires a search for 10 of the 600 primitive elements of $GF(2^{10})$ where the mapping will be isomorphic, such as $α(x) = x^7+x^5+x^4+x^2+x$ The 10 by 10 bit mapping matrix and its inverse are computed based on $α(x)$ and $β(x)$. The one time search for a working $α(x)$ is reasonably fast enough for $GF(2^{32})$ or so.

Comment: @ccorn and to the OP - in software, carryless multiply, such as X86 64 bit PCLMULQDQ (1 micro op on current X86), can multiply two 64 operands producing a 128 bit result. $A*B \ mod  \ P$ can be calculated as $M = A*B$, $Q = M*P^{-1}$, $A*B \ mod \ P = M \ xor \ (Q*P)$ , where $P^{-1}$ is a pre-calculated constant. 3 multiplies and one xor.

Comment: @HenrickDavis - for software, having to do a k by k bit matrix multiply to map to the composite field, doing some math in the composite field, then another k by k bit matrix multiply to map back doesn't seem like it would benefit a software implementation, although it generally reduces gate count for a hardware implementation. If a processor has a carryless multiply, that would save a lot for a software implementation.